# Streaming with Tweepy: randomly getting 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm using the Tweepy library to track a hashtag (I'm using the streaming API) and I save to a file on my hard drive after a certain number of records. My code works and I leave it running. After some time, I randomly get the following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
raise exception
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

If I wait a bit and restart, the program starts running but I soon get the error again.

I also noticed that by the time I get home from work in the evening, the error would have occured and from then onwards even if I restart, I will keep on getting the error until basically hours later.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and if so, what was the solution?

I'm running python 2.7 and Tweepy 3.5

Thanks

Updates: My code

```
trackList = '#GOP'
try:
    listen = myListener.SListener(api)
    stream = Stream(auth, listen)
    stream.filter(track=trackList) 

except Exception, inst:
    print "An unexpected error occured"
    print (type(inst))
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    filename, lineno, funname, line = traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1]
    print('{}:{}, in {}\n    {}'.format(filename, lineno, funname, line))
```

And in myListener.py

```
def on_status(self, status):
    try:
        self.output.write(status + "\n")
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter >= 5000:
            self.output.close()
            self.output  = open(time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.json', 'w')
            self.counter = 0

        return

    except Exception, inst:
        print "An unexpected error occured in Listener"
        print (type(inst))
        _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
        filename, lineno, funname, line = traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1]
        print('{}:{}, in {}\n    {}'.format(filename, lineno, funname, line))
        pass
```

Comment: Could you add your code? (Minimal if possible)

Comment: I've added my code

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a minimal code on how you are passing your hashtag? This can be either related to the way you are feeding hashtag or an open issue in tweepy.

This particular issue regarding streaming is very similar to what you are experiencing: [TypeError: expected string or buffer in streaming module #748](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/748)

Comment: Please do not post such content as an answer since it does not specifically give a solution. Next time, go for a comment :)

Comment: My apologies, but i didnt have enough reputation to comment on this as i have just started using stackoverflow. I had experience a similar issue few days back so i thought i could help.